# SASS Compiler complains about invalid CSS (a missing selector)

Tags: css, sass

I'm new to SASS and can't figure out why the following code is causing an error:

```
#dPageContainer {
    position: relative;

    /* There is a comment here in my code. */ 
    height: 0px; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    z-index: 2;

    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

    background-color: white;
}
```

The SASS compiler gives me this error:

`Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "  padding-top": expected selector or at-rule, was ": 10px;"`

Comment: Are there any hidden chars? Delete the line and re-type it.

Comment: I tried removing both the height and padding directives, and I got this error: "StringScanner::Error: regexp buffer overflow" I am using Koala for the compilation; maybe this is a bug in the application?

Comment: Definitely sounds strange and not like a normal SASS behavior…

Comment: The code compiles fine via commandline.  You aren't using any "new" features that might lead me to believe Koala is compiling with an older version of Sass.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem was caused by a bug in the Koala SASS compiler. I compiled the .scss file using the SASS command line tool and it worked fine.